# Using auto keyword to fill doubly-indexed vector

Tags: c++, vector

Trying to better learn the `auto` keyword.  I'd like to allocate a doubly-indexed `vector` using the `auto` keyword, but when I print the vector (which should be all `0`'s), it instead prints empty space, but in the correct "shape" of the vector.

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void DisplayVector(const std::vector<std::vector<double> >& vec)
{
  std::cout << "vector: \n\n";
  for (auto i : vec)
    {
      for (auto j : i)
        {
          std::cout << j << " ";
        }
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > vec1, vec2;

  /* what I want to work */
  vec1.resize(5);
  for (auto i : vec1)
    {
      i.resize(3);
    }
  DisplayVector(vec1);

  /* "old" way of doing it */
  vec2.resize(5);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
      vec2[i].resize(3);
    }
  DisplayVector(vec2);

}
```

This results in

```
vector: 







vector: 

0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

What is the proper method of doing this?  Is one preferred?  Also accepting critiques on code implementation :)

Comment: `auto i: vec1` makes a copy of each vector and resizes that copy. Try using `auto& i: vec1`.

Comment: Or `const auto&` if you are only going to read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your usage, on its own, `auto` will work with values, so will resize copies of the vectors within `vec1`.

Change the loop with vec1 to use a reference

```
for (auto &i : vec1)
{
  i.resize(3);
}
```

Also change both loops within `DisplayVector()` to use `const auto &` (a `const` reference rather than by value).   That won't change the output, but will avoid copying vectors around.

Note:  v154c1 and Neil kirk have said essentially the same things in comments.